# What does question mark in ".includes?" mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

I ran across this piece of code and was wondering what the ? means in this case? It is part of an if statement condition

```
if user_input.include? "s"
```

what does the "?" mean?

sorry, i'm new to ruby

Comment: That is a ruby convention for methods which return boolean values.  Other examples: `.kind_of?` to determine if the object is of a class, `.nil?` to determine if it is nil. The `?` isn't an operator, but rather an actual part of the method name.

Answer (score 6):

The `?` is part of the method name.

In Ruby, method names are allowed to end in a `?` or an `!`. Typically, `?` indicates a predicate (a method that returns a Boolean), and `!` indicates a destructive operation (something that modifies the receiver object).